# Alternatives to CSS:hover for iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, css, ipad

I have many 300x200px divs(.contentUser) rendering representing users.

```
contentUser:hover(over) 
    ->shows another div(.contetnButtonWrap) sliding in with buttons.
contentUser:hover(out)
    -> contentButtonWrap slides out again
```

This works fine with CSS on any device I have tested so far except iPad(no hover). I tried with :active but it didn't work

So on iPad instead of `hover(over)` I use `onclick`:

```
function alternativeHover() {
    var userDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('contentUser');
    [].forEach.call(userDivs, function(e){
        e.onclick = function() {
            var target = e.getElementsByClassName('contentButtonWrap');
            e.style.backgroundSize='450px 300px';
            e.style.outline='3px solid green';
            target[0].style.left=0;
        };
    });
};
```

I have 3 questions:

- Is this really the best that can be done in this case?
- How to handle the `hover(out)`, its a div so it doesn't grab focus so I can not use `onblur`! And I would not like to have to check pixels on `mousemove` or anything like that.
- Why doesn't hover work on iPad if it works on Android smartphones and iPhones?